# R: wald test on multivariate regression model

Tags: r, regression

I have to perform a Wald-Test on the estimated coefficients of a multivariate linear equation model, estimated with `systemfit`. The command `waldtest.systemfit` does not work, R does not know it (even though i have installed the package). I tried to solve it with `linearHypothesis()` but R gives me following message:

> Error in solve(restrict.matrix %*% vcov %*% t(restrict.matrix)) :
>   fejl under evaluering af argument 'a' under valg af metode for
>   funktion 'solve': Error in restrict.matrix %*% vcov : non-conformable
>   arguments

My equation system has the following form:

```
CDSSurReg = systemfit(list(Y~CDSSur[,3] + Dummy1 + Dummy2, ...  Y~CDSSur[,20] + Dummy1 + Dummy2,  Y~CDSSur[,21] + Dummy1 + Dummy2), method = "SUR")
```

With 19 equations in total.

I want to test if the average `Dummy1 - Coefficient` is significantly different from zero.

Comment: Instead of posting a question with an ellipsis in your formula and no data, you should find a dataset in the package, post a library call to the package first, and then post a model specification that will result in an object that supports a proper demonstration.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example It's not required but it will help you get answers.